# Buscando una función de restricción en POO

Tags: python, python-2.7

El siguiente código que hemos desarrollado consta de una clase "Partida", que a su vez contiene una serie de métodos que simulan un juego. El juego consta de 4 participantes que a lo largo de 6 rondas (ver "emparejamientos") muestran y observan las señales de sus parejas. Las señales que son mostradas por cada participante son almacenadas en su memoria de señales mostradas y las señales que son observadas son almacenadas en su memoria de señales observadas. Con una ecuación calculamos la probabilidad de que en cada ronda un participante genere una señal, dependiendo de la memoria y de otras variables.

En el código actual, para calcular la probabilidad de producción de una señal en una ronda determinada (with_b) por un jugador determinado, se tiene en cuenta el cómputo total de señales almacenadas en las memoria desde el inicio del juego. Es decir, las señales que se han ido almacenando desde el inicio del juego determinan en cierta medida lo que se va a producir.

Me gustaría ser flexible en este aspecto. ¿Cómo podría implementar en el código la opción de que en cada ronda solo se tenga en cuenta la memoria almacenada de las últimas x generaciones?

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[op], inst.men_observadas[op], self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['Senal 1', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 3', 'Senal 4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)],
                       [(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)]]
    s=[1,0,0,0]

    muestras = [{'b':0.0, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02} for _ in range(1000)]

    simulaciones = 100
    estadisticas = {jugador:{muestra:{senal:[0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1)]
                        for senal in senales}
                            for muestra in range(len(muestras))}
                                for jugador in jugadores}


    for mu in range(len(muestras)):
        for _ in range(simulaciones):
            juego = Partida(jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, s, muestras[mu]['b'],muestras[mu]['x'], muestras[mu]['m'])
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

        with open('salidav4.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
            writer =csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            writer.writerow(['Muestra' ,'Jugador', 'Ronda', 'b', 'x', 'm'] + senales)

            for jugador in jugadores:
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos)+1):
                        aux = [estadisticas[jugador][mu][senal][ronda-1] for senal in senales]
                        writer.writerow([mu+1, jugador, ronda, muestras[mu]['b'], muestras[mu]['x'], muestras[mu]['m']]+aux)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @FJSevilla quizá entiendes el código mejor que nadie. Hasta ahora he intentado definir algún método que elimine la memoria anterior a las últimas 3 rondas. Pero no parece una solución muy buena. Lo suyo sería poder declarar una variable tipo memoria=3 o memoria=4, por ejemplo, que automáticamente aplicara el método deseado. Cualquier pista se agradece. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla. He vuelto de nuevo al código. Me he dado cuenta de que no puedo borrar la memoria antigua con el código que propuse abajo porque mem_mostradas y mem_observadas son diccionarios. Sigo sin saber cómo limitar la cantidad de memoria a tres generaciones. ¿Se te ocurre algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo que tu bola de nieve sigue creciendo... XD. Requieres ir tenindo en cuenta solo los datos de x generaciones e ir borrando los datos más viejos en principio necesitarias algún método que permita almacenar el orden.

La idea más simple es prescindir del diccionario para guardar las memorias y pasarnos a una lista. Esto implica perder eficiencia tanto en tiempo de ejecución como en memoria pero a cambio nos permite saber que generación obtuvo una determinada salida.

Una lista sería la idea básica pero se puede mejorar usando una cola limitada a x items. Si el límite de memoria es 3 la cola va añadiendo señales hasta llegar a 3, a partir de ese momento al añadir una señal se elimina la más antigua por lo que las memorias siempre contienen las últimas tres señales.

Esto ya existe en Python implementado para nosotros en la biblioteca `collections` y se llama [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque). Es parecido a una lista pero las operaciones propias de una cola (añadir y extraer elementos por los extremos) son mucho más eficientes. Además permite pasarle el atributo `maxlen` que hace lo explicado en el párrafo anterior sin que nosotros tengamos que hacer nada.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
from collections import deque

cola = deque(maxlen = 3)
print cola
cola.append(1)
print cola
cola.append(2)
print cola
cola .append(3)
print cola
cola.append(4)
print cola
cola.append(5)
print cola
```

La salida nos muestra claramente el funcionamiento explicado antes:

> deque([], maxlen=3)
>   deque([1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque), maxlen=3)
>   deque([1, 2], maxlen=3)
>   deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
>   deque([2, 3, 4], maxlen=3)
>   deque([3, 4, 5], maxlen=3)

Para adaptar esta idea a tu código hay que cambiar algunas lineas de tu clase `Partida`. Básicamente necesitamos usar el método `men_observadas.count(senal)` para sustituir `men_observadas[senal]` a la hora de obtener cuantas veces aparece una señal en la memoria y usar `append` en vez de incrementar en uno el contador como haciamos antes para agregar una nueva señal a la memoria, sería algo así:

```
from random import random, sample
from bisect import bisect
from collections import deque
import csv

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, jugadores, menLen, emparejamientos, senales, s, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.s = s
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(menLen)
                            for pareja in emparejamientos[0]
                                for nombre in pareja}
        self.memoria = list()


    def generar_senales(self):

        def with_b(muestra, observa, s, r):
            if not (muestra == observa == 0):
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * self.b * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            else:
                result = ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra/r) + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa/r) + ((0.98) * 0 * s) + ((self.m / 8))
            return result

        def choice(opciones, probs):
            probAcumuladas = list()
            aux = 0
            for p in probs:
                aux += p
                probAcumuladas.append(aux)
            r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
            op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
            return opciones[op]

        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores.keys(), self.senales))


        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = dict.fromkeys(self.jugadores.keys())
            for nombre, inst in self.jugadores.items():
                probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas.count(op), inst.mem_observadas.count(op), self.s[indx], r)
                            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
                eleccs[nombre] = choice(self.senales, probs)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs


    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens =  self.generar_senales()
        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)

            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_observadas.append(senales[jugador2])
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_observadas.append(senales[jugador1])
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas.append(senales[jugador1])
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas.append(senales[jugador2])

            #El código siguente es solo para imprimir las memorias en cada ronda para ver el funcionamiento.
            ##Debe eliminarse cuando corras tu codigo completo.
            print('Memorias ronda {}:'.format(n+1))
            for jugador, men in self.jugadores.items():
                print('    Memoria observada de jugador {}:{}'.format(jugador, list(men.mem_observadas)))
                print('    Memoria mostrada de jugador {}:{}'.format(jugador, list(men.mem_mostradas)))



    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, menLen):
            self.mem_mostradas = deque(maxlen=menLen)
            self.mem_observadas = deque(maxlen=menLen)



def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ['Senal 1', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 3', 'Senal 4']
    emparejamientos = [[(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)],
                       [(1,2),(3,4)],
                       [(1,3),(2,4)],
                       [(1,4),(2,3)]]
    s=[1,0,0,0]
    muestras = {'b':0.0, 'x':0.5, 'm':0.02} 
    menLen = 3
    simulaciones = 1
    juego = Partida(jugadores, menLen, emparejamientos, senales, s, muestras['b'],muestras['x'], muestras['m'])
    juego.jugar()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

He eliminado el código donde generas las 100 simulaciones y el que crea el csv de salida (puedes añadirlo después, los cambios son solo en la clase, en el `main` solo debes añadir en segundo lugar el parámetro `menLen` al instaciar la clase `Partida`.) Recuerda eliminar las líneas de impresión del método jugar, solo están para ver el funcionamiento. La salida es algo así:

> Memorias ronda 1:
>           Memoria observada de jugador 1:['Senal 2']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 1:['Senal 1']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 2:['Senal 1']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 2:['Senal 2']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 3:['Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 3:['Senal 3']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 4:['Senal 3']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 4:['Senal 4']
>   Memorias ronda 2:
>           Memoria observada de jugador 1:['Senal 2', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 1:['Senal 1', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 2:['Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 2:['Senal 2', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 3:['Senal 3', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 4:['Senal 3', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>   Memorias ronda 3:
>           Memoria observada de jugador 1:['Senal 2', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 1:['Senal 1', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 2:['Senal 1', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 2:['Senal 2', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 3:['Senal 3', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 4:['Senal 3', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>   Memorias ronda 4:
>           Memoria observada de jugador 1:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 1:['Senal 1', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 2']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 2:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 2']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 2:['Senal 1', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 3:['Senal 1', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 4:['Senal 1', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>   Memorias ronda 5:
>           Memoria observada de jugador 1:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 1:['Senal 4', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 2:['Senal 4', 'Senal 2', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 2:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>   Memorias ronda 6:
>          Memoria observada de jugador 1:['Senal 4', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 1:['Senal 2', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 2:['Senal 2', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 2:['Senal 4', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 3:['Senal 4', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 4']
>           Memoria observada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 1', 'Senal 1']
>           Memoria mostrada de jugador 4:['Senal 4', 'Senal 4', 'Senal 4']

Como podemos observar la memoria se limita siempre a las tres últimas señales recibidas(las últimas 3 rondas). Cambiando el parámetro `menLen` podemos especificar el tamaño de la memoria.

Comment: Alucino cómo lo haces de fácil... Gracias. Veo que me falta también aprender mucho sobre las posibilidades de las bibliotecas de Python. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es que la función `choice` reciba un argumento que indique el número de generaciones a manejar:

```
 def choice(opciones, probs, ngeneraciones=None):
        probAcumuladas = list()
        aux = 0
        for p in probs[:ngeneraciones]:
          ...
```

Por defecto, `ngeneraciones` vale `None`, que tomaría todas las generaciones almacenadas. Si lo prefieres, el número de generaciones podría ser una variable de estado de tu simulación (eg: `self.ngeneraciones`)

Recomendarte que mejores la orientación a objetos. El modelo debería responder a preguntas como *¿qué entidades existen?* y *¿cómo interaccionan estas entidades?*. Por tu estilo, se nota que estás empezando y que usas la orientación de objetos para empaquetar funciones y variables de estado en módulos ejecutables que no son nada reusables. Intenta crear una clase por entidad y dales métodos que alteren sus estados.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por la respuesta @ChemaCortes. En efecto, estoy aprendiendo. Imagino que son unos años lo que lleva eso de ser un principiante ;)

He intentado cambiar el código con lo que comentas pero no consigo el efecto deseado. Parece desaparecer por completo el registro de señales en el csv. Como si los participantes olvidaran todo y la producción de señales fuera cero en todas las generaciones.

He intentado también otra solución. En la función `def jugar(self):` he añadido al final un fragmento de código como sigue:

```
if n >= 3:
    del self.memoria[0]
```

La idea es que cada participante recuerde solo las 3 últimas rondas que ha jugado (es decir que la probabilidad de producción de señales dependa de la memoria de las últimas 3 rondas, no de toda la lista. Sin embargo, nuevamente, el csv obtenido aparece sin registro de memoria.

Answer (score 0):

He vuelto a intentar resolver este problema que planteé. Esto es, que en cada generación en que el juego produce señales, el programa limite la memoria guardada a 3 generaciones del juego. Así, a partir de la cuarta generación tan sólo se contarían las últimas 3 generaciones en la memoria de señales.

He comprobado que no puedo borrar la memoria antigua de señales de los diccionarios `mem_mostradas` y `men_observadas` dado que los diccionarios no tienen orden.

Estaba intentando limitar a tres generaciones dicha memoria modificando la función `def choice` de la siguiente manera:

```
probs = [with_b(inst.mem_mostradas[-3:][op], inst.men_observadas[-3:][op], self.s[indx], r)
               for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)]
```

Como puede observarse, el comando `[-3:]` que funcionaría si la memoria fuera una lista, me da obviamente un error.

Sigo sin tener ni idea de cómo resolver este problema.

Comentarios bienvenidos.